# Anything obvious in optimization missed in my left join query?

Tags: mysql, innodb, join

I've really simple join statement, which take a lot time to complete. I would like to know if I'm missing any obvious optimization steps i could take.

So I've got two tables, with the following `create` statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `objects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `positive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feature_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cell_size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `edge_size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_name` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `frame_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `left_coord` tinyblob,
  `right_coord` tinyblob,
  `image_info_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_data_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_data_size` tinyblob,
  `opcode` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `object_name` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pose` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tilt_angle` float DEFAULT '0',
  `weight_id` float NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `video_data_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `image_info_id` (`image_info_id`),
  KEY `feature_id` (`feature_id`),
  KEY `on_ind` (`object_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `feature_link` FOREIGN KEY (`feature_id`) REFERENCES `features` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `image_info_link` FOREIGN KEY (`image_info_id`) REFERENCES `image_info` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1283145 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And this one:

```
CREATE TABLE `uchog7x7` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uchog7x7` blob,
  `iuchog7x7` blob,
  `needs_update` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `needs_update` (`needs_update`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I'm performing the following query:

```
SELECT 
    objects.id
FROM
    objects
        LEFT JOIN
    uchog7x7 ON objects.id = uchog7x7.id
WHERE
    uchog7x7.needs_update = 1
        AND uchog7x7.id IS NOT NULL
        AND object_name = 'face'
```

This query takes a lot of time to complete. Table named `objects` has `1,035,526` records, table `uchog7x7` contains `639,322` objects.

When I do explain I get the following:

[image]

I'm not using file-per-table.

Am I missing something obvious explaining why does it take a lot of time to complete? My guess is that somehow non-desirable full table scans happen, but I do not know for sure.

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure your foreign keys are indexed and try again. Also, you might try a covering index with the columns specified in your where statement. These are broad brush stroke recommendations to get you somewhere fast. Fine tune as necessary.

Comment: What does it mean a long time?

Comment: The `WHERE uchog7x7.needs_update = 1` makes the quey an `INNER JOIN`. And the `uchog7x7.id IS NOT NULL` is redundant.

Comment: think INNER JOIN will work better, but also - what is mean "take a lot time"? and second - how many records it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  o.id
    FROM  objects AS o
    JOIN  uchog7x7  ON o.id = u.id  -- Not LEFT
    WHERE  u.needs_update = 1
      -- AND  u.id IS NOT NULL   -- not needed
      AND  o.object_name = 'face'
```

Don't use `CHAR()` unless the value is a constant length.

What fraction of the rows have 'face'?  What percentage have `needs_update`?

The optimizer, when given no good choice, starts with the smaller table.  According to `EXPLAIN`, it found about 1 row with "needs_update".  Probably that is far off, and you need to remove that index.

What version of MySQL are you using?  5.7 has improved the 'cost models', and might do a better job.

Other notes:

Don't use `tinyblob`; use `VARBINARY(255)` instead.

Why are `*coord` and `image_data_size` going into blobs; they sound like numeric values?

What will you do with the ids that come back from the query?  Some heavy-duty image processing?  If so, consider adding `LIMIT 1` (or `LIMIT 10`) so that the query comes back faster.  I assume you will pick up others later.

Comment: Generally, thank you - you hint about inner join has sent me in the right direction. Also, thank you for your binary vs tinyblob hint - I will investigate since it is not clear for me why is it supposed to be better. Thanks!

Comment: @sof_dff - the diff between binary and tinyblob is subtle -- When a select needs to create a tmp table, it will try to use MEMORY which is more efficient.  But in certain cases (including existence of BLOB or TEXT), it will use MyISAM instead.  Still better is to use `VARBINARY(...)` with a realistic max size.